# Como subdividir un dato de una columna nvarchar en tres columnas distintas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

En mi base de datos SQL SERVER está cargada la dirección en un nvarchar con este formato:
"120 E/ 25 Y 26 Nº 1439". En algunos casos no se respeta, pero no tendria problema en modificarlos a mano. Lo que hice yo fue separarlo en distintas columnas para obligar siempre a respetar ese formato. Por ejemplo:

Calle - 120
PrimerEntrecalle - 25
SegundaEntrecalle - 26
Numero - 1439

Que consulta debo hacer para reemplazar todas las direcciones con el viejo formato a mis nuevas columnas?

Comment: ¿Has probado con el Replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo entender que esto es lo que necesitas:

```
WITH DATOS AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(DIRECCION, 1, CHARINDEX('E/',DIRECCION) - 1) AS CALLE,
           SUBSTRING(DIRECCION, CHARINDEX('E/',DIRECCION) + 2, CHARINDEX('Y',DIRECCION) - (CHARINDEX('E/',DIRECCION) + 2) ) AS PRIMER_ENTRECALLE,
           SUBSTRING(DIRECCION, CHARINDEX('Y',DIRECCION) + 1, CHARINDEX('Nº',DIRECCION) - (CHARINDEX('Y',DIRECCION) + 1) ) AS SEGUNDA_ENTRECALLE,
           SUBSTRING(DIRECCION, CHARINDEX('Nº',DIRECCION) + 2, LEN(DIRECCION) + 1 - (CHARINDEX('Nº',DIRECCION) + 2) ) AS NUMERO
    FROM [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_ANTIGUA]
    -- Filtra las direcciones que si cumplen con el formato
    WHERE DIRECCION LIKE '[0-9]% E/ [0-9]% Y [0-9]% Nº [0-9]%'
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_NUEVA]
SELECT 'Calle - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CALLE)) AS CALLE_NUEVO_FORMATO,
       'PrimerEntrecalle - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(PRIMER_ENTRECALLE)) + ' SegundaEntrecalle - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SEGUNDA_ENTRECALLE)) AS ENTTRECALLE_NUEVO_FORMATO,
       'Numero - ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(NUMERO)) AS NUMERO_NUEVO_FORMATO
FROM DATOS
```

Encuentra direcciones que no cumplen el formato

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_ANTIGUA]
WHERE DIRECCION NOT LIKE '[0-9]% E/ [0-9]% Y [0-9]% Nº [0-9]%'
```

Ejemplo:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_ANTIGUA]    Script Date: 14/07/2019 3:03:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_ANTIGUA](
    [DIRECCION] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_NUEVA]    Script Date: 14/07/2019 3:03:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_NUEVA](
    [CALLE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ENTRECALLE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NUMERO] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_ANTIGUA] ([DIRECCION]) VALUES (N'120 E/ 25 Y 26 Nº 1439')
INSERT [dbo].[TB_DIRECCION_ANTIGUA] ([DIRECCION]) VALUES (N'9 E/ 225 Y 226 Nº 5')
```

Comment: Hola Nicolas, gracias por tu ayuda. Entendiste perfectamente lo que necesito y funciona. El inconveniente esta en los campos que no respetan ese formato, me lanza este error: Se pasó un parámetro de longitud no válido a la función LEFT o SUBSTRING. Como podría filtrar en el WHERE para afectar solo las direcciones que respetan ese formato? Por ejemplo, hay direcciones cargadas como "Diagonal 79 y 48", o "calle falsa 123". Esas las cambiaria a mano

Comment: Hola andeehr, edite la respuesta y agregue el WHERE para obtener las direcciones que si cumplen el formato, y una consulta para identificar las direcciones que no cumplen el formato.